# How to catch exception thrown in ASP.NET Core Razor page middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have intranet.net core razor app with default exception handling setting as follows:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

I have one custom middleware to deal with Windows authentication with identity membership and check the user id application user. If not the application user, app throws one exception as follows:

```
if (user != null)
{
    await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

    context.User = await signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);

    _logger.LogInformation($"User with id {user.Id}, name {user.UserName} successfully signed in");
}
else
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"User cannot be found in identity store.");

    throw new System.InvalidOperationException($"user not found.");
}
```

In production, the exception is never caught instead of 500 error. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you had the chance the checking your app log?  In particular from which line you are getting the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to catch exception thrown in .net core Razor page middleware?

Well, in .NET 6/7 or higher, you  can use [problem details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#problem-details) extentison method, which will bind the responses for all HTTP client and server errors. Problem details which actually implements [IProblemDetailsService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iproblemdetailsservice?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that helps keeping your exception/errors within asp.net core app. This extension method is pretty straight forward in terms of its implementation. You can simply include following line:

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
```

**Note:** Microsoft doesn't recommned to expose error details other than development environment due to the security risk.

[image]

**Can be customize:**

Most importantly, Problme details extension method is an automatic error writer, which can be customized the response by using [CustomizeProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#customize-problem-details) and your modification can be applied to all auto-generated problem details. You can do as following:

```
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails(options =>
    options.CustomizeProblemDetails = ctx =>
            ctx.ProblemDetails.Extensions.Add("nodeId", Environment.MachineName));
```

In addition, `ProblemDetails.Extensions` is a `IDictionary` type which contains `IDictionary<string, object?>`, so any additional information can be passed here.

[image]

**Note:** Please be informed that, while using a custom IProblemDetailsWriter, the custom IProblemDetailsWriter must be registered before calling AddRazorPages, AddControllers, AddControllersWithViews, or AddMvc. [Please refer to this official document for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&preserve-view=true#custom-iproblemdetailswriter)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using a custom middleware.

First, I'm assuming that you don't want to allow anonymous access to anything. You can change the default policy to authenticate users;

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
...
```

The first request a user makes will be anonymous. The web server will then respond with a 401. The browser will then either authenticate automatically, or prompt the user for credentials.

That would be sufficient, if you wanted to manage permissions using windows group memberships.

Note that you can test at runtime if the web server has been configured to authenticate automatically;

```cs
services.GetService<IEnumerable<IServerIntegratedAuth>>()
    .Any(a => a.IsEnabled);
```

If you want to manage roles and permissions using `SignInManager`, then you could implement an `IClaimsTransformation` service to return the result from `.CreateUserPrincipalAsync()`.